# unknown column in where... its defined right there!

Tags: sql, mysql

im using this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr.competitorID AS compID, pr.age, CONCAT(pr.firstname, ' ', pr.lastname)AS name
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=1 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS '100m'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=25 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS '200m'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=37 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS '400m'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=49 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS '800m'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=61 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS '1500m'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=67 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS '3000m'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=69 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS 'Javelin'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=81 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS 'Shot Put'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=93 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS 'Discus'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=105 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS 'High Jump'
, (SELECT  participation_reports.points FROM participation_reports WHERE participation_reports.heatEventID=117 AND participation_reports.competitorID=compID LIMIT 1) AS 'Long Jump'
, SUM(pr.points) AS total
FROM participation_reports AS pr
JOIN event_data ON event_data.eventID=pr.heatEventID
WHERE event_data.minAge <= pr.age AND event_data.maxAge >= pr.age AND sex = 'F' AND total > 0 LIMIT 30
```

but im getting this error: 'undefined column "total" in "where clause"'

---

**Update:** 
cheers guys,
anyone care to explain the difference between having and where (also aliased vs defined)

Comment: WHERE is a pre-condition.. Rows must match this condition before they will be included in the result.  HAVING is a post-condition.  The result is further filtered by this extra condition set.  It's precisely for this type of case when you are using aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not defined, it's aliased, and you can't do it like that... try the HAVING clause:

```
FROM participation_reports AS pr 
JOIN event_data ON event_data.eventID=pr.heatEventID 
WHERE event_data.minAge <= pr.age AND event_data.maxAge >= pr.age AND sex = 'F'
HAVING SUM(pr.points) > 0 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking this query will also need a GROUP BY clause, or will the DISTINCT keyword serve that purpose?

Comment: I would use one, but I guess it worked without it.. I didn't evaluate the whole query just touched on the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the column alias in the where clause.  You have to say where SUM(pr.points) > 0.

Unfortunately, you can't do that either.  You have to say `HAVING sum(pr.points) > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the `participation_reports` table to make sure it's there.  Your WHERE clause has it, but the table it's referring to might not.  Check to see.

Answer (score 0):

you're getting bitten by SQL's brain-damaging syntax.  consider `SELECT`, `FROM`, `JOIN` and `WHERE` as functions.  then the semantics can be written as:

```
SELECT(
  WHERE(
    FROM(JOIN(R1, R2, COND))
  , COND
  )
, COLS
);
```

as you can see, your `total` column name is not in scope in the WHERE clause.